# Determinant of Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the determinant of the matrix of transformation does not 
depend on the choice of ordered basis. Can you give the proof? 
I start doing it using the definition but I got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that if $A$ and $B$ are two matrices representing the same linear transformation $T$, then $A$ and $B$ are [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity). Now use that the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants of the factors.

This result is what allows one to *define* the determinant of a linear transformation.

Comment: There is a way to define the determinant of a linear map without using matrix determinants and Binet's formula: If $f\colon V\to V$ is a linear map, then $f$ induces linear maps $\bigwedge^kf\colon\bigwedge^k V\to\bigwedge^kV$ $(k=1,\dots,n=\dim V)$; since $\bigwedge^nV$ is one dimensional, $\bigwedge^nf$ is the multiplication by a scalar, which is defined to be the determinant of $f$. Using the exterior algebra is the easiest way to prove the (generalized) Laplace development. Of course this is far from elementary.

Comment: I don't get the used of the product of the determinant to

Comment: I don't get the used of the product of the determinants to show that the transformation does not depend on the choice of ordered basis.